# cambiar clase de todos los elementos dentro de tr definido

Tags: javascript, html, html-tabla

Tengo varios elementos de tabla,
tr con clase header odd / header even que se muestran, siempre visibles
y entre ellos otros tr con clases odd y even que están ocultos

```
<tr style="display: none; height: 0px;" role="row" class="odd" data-dt-row="2"><td style="border-right: hidden;" data-dt-row="2" data-dt-column="0"></td><td colspan="" style="" class="" data-dt-row="2" data-dt-column="1"></td><td class="" style=" " data-dt-row="2" data-dt-column="2">FE170 - Venta Internet</td></tr>
<td style="border-right: hidden;" data-dt-row="3" data-dt-column="0"></td><td colspan="" style="" class="" data-dt-row="3" data-dt-column="1"></td><td class="" style=" " data-dt-row="3" data-dt-column="2">NM270 - Venta Internet</td>
```

y quiero cambiar a style="display: block;" todos los tr con clase odd y even contenidos dentro del tr que tiene clase header odd o header even.

Cómo puedo hacer ésto? Se que con $(this).nextAll o algo así pero no se muy bien como es el funcionamiento de ésto

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende muy bien. Pon un ejemplo completo que comprenda los casos que quieres cambiar. Hablas de una clase `header` y de una clase `even` por ejemplo que no veo por ningún lado en el HTML que compartes en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, dentro de la función de jquery puedes poner infinidad de rutas para llegar a hacer un emparejamiento con algún selector es muy similar al css

```
$("tr.header .odd").css("display", "block");
```

El anterior script tomara todos los elementos con la clase `odd` que esten dentro de un elemento `<tr>` con la clase `header` y les agregara el estilo display:block